# DNS and custom Domain

Tags: custom-domain

I got a free domain from freenom (.gq) and i tried connecting it to my github repo (genarcy.github.io) by putting in githubs dns but it wouldnt work. it keeps saying dns unsuccessful. The picture below is my dns. The document github i didnt understand[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add the domain to your GitHub repo settings > pages > custom domain